# Is there a way to make freshen tests fail on undefined tests?

Tags: python, django, bdd, nose, nosetests

By default when I run a freshen scenario, which contains an undefined given/when/then clause, that test is simply marked as undefined. No further helpful message as to what actually isn't defined is given. Is there a way to change this behavior to get more information what exactly was undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open ticket requesting this at https://github.com/rlisagor/freshen/issues/16
I also attached a link to a github branch implementing this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this gives a little more info:

```
./manage.py test -- -v
```

There is a patch to improve thing like this on github and the author promised to merge it but it seems he didn't.

https://github.com/rlisagor/freshen/pull/8